# How to run a bash script in terminal from the applications menu in elementary OS 5.1

Tags: slingshot, script

I tried to add an application menu item to launch a simple bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash 
GTK_CSD=0 grass74
```

on terminal to start an application, both with the AppEditor utility and manually by entering the path of the script in the .desktop file:

```
Exec=/home/andrea/Applicazioni/grass74.sh
```

but either way it doesn't work.
The use of a bash script to start the program stems from the fact that the original program launcher does not work in Elementary OS while it works fine in Ubuntu 18.04 and Mint 19.3.
The script works by launching it from the terminal with ./grass74.sh but does not work by clicking on the application menu icon.
I thought the problem could arise from the elementary OS terminal emulator because the application starts from the terminal, but I was not able to understand how to solve it.

Comment: Does it work if you add bash to the Exec line? Something like this:  `Exec=bash /home/andrea/Applicazioni/grass74.sh `

Comment: Unfortunately neither with _bash_ nor with _bash -c_ with or without quotation marks for _/path/to/grass74.sh_

Comment: There's an app called `alacarte` that may help you do it. You can download it from Appcenter. Is also known as "main menu"

Comment: I used AppEditor menu utility (similar to Alacarte) but without being able to solve the problem.